# socket.io websocket fallbacks

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to use dotcloud with node.js + socket.io for realtime applications.

But they don't support websockets.

Will there be noticeable bandwidth or performance degradation by relying purely on fallbacks?

Is it worth it to use my own server? Linode or aws or whatnot.

Thanks.

Comment: Websockets are indeed faster. It's only worth it in a professional setting (i.e. just use fallbacks for toys / prototypes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm implementing an instant messaging system which depends completely on websocket. As the web is evolving quite fast and websocket was in the web standard, I decided to use flash websocket fallback for any browser that don't support it by default (Firefox, Opera). Here is what you may want to know:

1. I use websocket. I use a [pure websocket server](http://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server). I don't use any other protocols. I don't use socket.io. I must say that if you decide to use only websocket, you won't have benefit from socket.io lib, even the development time. It only adds unnecessary overhead to your server because of multiple transportation layers support.
2. At client side, I use websocket + [flash websocket fallback](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) which implements websocket specs using flash socket and I would say that there's no noticable difference. The only thing you should know that is due to the "same origin policy", you may need to serve flash socket policy request your own (run on port 843 by default) to allow the flash socket to connect in.
3. We're currently using private server because we have a dedicated sysadmin. However, it's better if you can just focus on doing what you intended to do, and not on unwanted things. Oh, and sometimes, it's better if you have complete control of your own server :-).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Sorry about the late response but did you run into any problems with socket.io which caused you to not use it? I'm asking because it seems like socket.io is what *everyone uses, and I haven't considered not using it. But I am considering following your example.

Comment: I also considered socket.io at the beginning. However, once socket.io is used at one side (server or client), you have to stick with it at both sides. Hence, your "websocket" app will be incompatible with any other standard implementations. This prevented me from going further. I think socket.io is good for fixing the outdated internet technology :).